# Wolfram generating different graphs for equivalent equations

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

Wolfram generates this funky graph for `eˣ = sin(x·y)`:

[image: funky]

Whereas for the equivalent `arcsin(eˣ)/x = y` we get this rather boring graph:

[image: boring]

Are they both correct?

Comment: Is that the exact input you gave it?

Comment: @Chappers - `e^x = sin(x*y)` vs `arcsin(e^x)/x = y`

Comment: $\arcsin(x)$ is only the inverse of $\sin(x)$ within the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. The equation cannot be solved uniquely for $x$

Comment: (that is, the equations are not equivalent)

Comment: To add to @Peter's comment: fix a value of $x$, say $x=-10$. Clearly $e^{-10}=\sin(-10y)$ has infinitely many solutions: $y\approx\frac\pi{10}k$, where $k\in\Bbb Z$. On the other hand, $\arcsin(e^{-10})/(-10) = y$ only has one solution, $y\approx0$.

Comment: Try drawing $$\frac{\arcsin(e^x)+k\pi}x = y$$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Wolfram Alpha making a bad guess at a sensible range to show, which is not obvious from the diagram. Clicking on the Open Code button reveals that it's interpreting the input as

```
ContourPlot[E^x == Sin[x y], {x, -151, 37}, {y, -95, 26}]
```

and because there are so many solutions to the equation in this region, it can't correctly guess how to join them up. If you ask for

```
plot e^x = sin(xy) for -1<x<1
```

you get a reasonably respectable-looking graph:

[image]

and specifying an appropriate range for `y` as well gives an even better one:

[image]

Of course, $\arcsin$ is not a true inverse to $\sin$, so the other graph only picks out one of these lines.